# How to validate a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a textbox in which the user will enter data in the following way.
e.g. 1.2-2012-2 
But it could also be; **12.5**-2010-4 (Emphasis on the first part)
My first approach was a `MaskedTextBox` but as the first part does not have a definite size, I can't use that. 
Now I want to validate the textbox. i.e. I will let the user enter what he/she wants to but in the end I want to know if he/she has entered it in the correct way.
e.g. If the user types a12.4/2012^14 (which is incorrect) I would know.
I have no idea how to convert this idea into code so please could someone guide me. 
If there's an alternative approach.

Comment: What technology is this for (e.g. winforms, wpf)?

Comment: what have you tried..what is that input..would `.` be always there in the input.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ not always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextChanged` event and `Regex` expression:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myRegex = new Regex(@"^(\d)+\.\d-(\d){4}-\d$");

    if (myRegex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
    {
        //Validation is ok
    }
    else
    {
        //Validation isn't ok
    }
}
```

I have tested this code. It's works. The only thing I don't know your pattern exactly but above one should work.

If . is optional then use this pattern: `@"^(\d)+(\.\d)*-(\d){4}-\d$"`

Comment: The . is optional  
What do I do now ?

Comment: If . is optional use star '\*': (\.)\*

Comment: or in your case @"^(\d)+(\.\d)*-(\d){4}-\d$"

Comment: One more question
What if I want the third part to contain only numbers less than 12 ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23844/discussion-between-algreat-and-waqas-ali)

Comment: you have not considered the fact that `.` can be optional

Answer (score 3):

I guess matched textbox cannot match inconsistent input so it's best to use regex here..

You can use this regex

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?-\d+-\d+$
```

You can then check the input like

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(input,regex))
     //valid
```

---

`^` depicts start of the string

`\d` represents a digit i.e 0-9

`+` matches preceding character 1 to many times..so `\d+` would match 1 to many digits

`?` matches preceding character 0 to 1 time.so `(\.\d+)?` matches a `.` followed by 1 to many digits **optionally**

`$` depicts the end of the string

with `^` and `$` we are specifying the start and end of the input else it can match the input in between..

Comment: can you explain what this would do exactly ?

Comment: so that means 
if in the third part I only want the user to enter 2 digits 
I type \d\d ???

Comment: The . is optional What do I do now ?

Comment: If you want 2 digits you type (\d){2}. See my answer